# SEO / Page Rank considerations for website redesigns

Tags: seo

We have done many website redesigns before for companies looking to bring themselves into the 21st century.  Most of them have low page rank when we are handed the project, so it is usually not a big concern of ours to maintain page rank.

However, we have recently obtained a client that is coming from a PHP-based architecture (we are a Microsoft .NET house), and one of the client's main concerns is the loss of their google page rank.  Obviously the pages that have a high page rank have PHP extensions.

My questions are as follows:

Will a 301 redirect maintain page rank for each page, or is there something else we need to consider?

Since there are hundreds of pages, is there a nice "industry-standard" way of performing multiple 301 redirects?  We are thinking of doing some URL rewriting of the PHP pages and performing the 301 redirect in the web form that we're redirecting to, but before we do this, we want to make sure there's not a better/cleaner way to do this.

Are there any other considerations we should take into account when dealing with a site of this magnitude with this amount of SEO success?

Any help, as always, is appreciated!

Comment: belongs on http://doctype.com

Comment: If I clear everything out but the 2nd question, can it stay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 301 is the recommended way (straight from Google's Webmaster Tools documentation) of changing URL's for content.  It is the "industry standard" and correct way of performing this task.

Your question is actually [very similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953682/thousands-of-301-redirects-bad-for-seo/), so you could check there for some more relevant responses.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the .Net Routing module. It would be a cleaner way to manage all those redirects in one go and in one spot.

You may have to set up IIS to send .php files to .Net

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 301 redirects maintain the authority of a website or a page for SEO. (Most tests show that 90% or more of the old authority is passed).

One other related search engine optimization tip is to be sure that each page redirects / resolves only one time. i.e. not as a www & non-www or with a trailing / and without.

Answer (score 0):

```
301
```

Redirect is Google Friendly and also Maintain Page Rank in Google. and second thing Web redesign is Best decision for Increase Page Rank and also Site Health.